# Adding inside wp-plugin jQuery script that receives JSON-formatted data, generated by php-function inside this plugin

Tags: plugins, ajax, json

I'm trying to add [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) chart in my plugin. It requires input data in json format. But I have some troubles with default json parser in jQuery. I've already read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) article, but still can't understand how can I add the chart in the plugin.

Can someone describe how does **getJSON()** works in wp plugins, and if it's possible to send data from php-function inside the plugin to the jQuery script inside this plugin in json format?

Here is example of highstock script, that I want to place in my plugin:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

And php code, that I want to put in function inside the plugin:

```
global $wpdb;

$table=$wpdb->prefix."table_name";

$query=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `date`,`value` FROM `".$table."` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2011' AND '2012' ORDER BY `date` ASC; ", ARRAY_A);

$i=0;
for($j=0; $j<sizeof($query); $j++) {
    $result[$j][]=strtotime($query[$j]['date'])*1000;
    $result[$j][]=(float)$query[$j]['value'];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Can anyone help? I'm really get tired to seek the solution.

Comment: Does the chart appear with the demo data provided on highcharts?

Comment: Yes, here is the [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/). I've changed some setting and wrote my own php-script to generate json-formatted date. It works pretty well outside the wp-plugin. The problem is to add this scripts inside the wp-plugin.

Comment: Are you familiar with the WordPress way of enqueueing scripts in your Plugin?

Comment: Of course, but I need to add both of this scripts to plugin. PHP-callback function generates json output; jquery script gets this data and builds the charts. The problem is getJSON() accepts url's only, not php functions.

Comment: Okay, in this case implement a callable PHP-File that delivers the JSON, and does nothing else. Maybe located at example.com/wp-content/plugins/yourplugin/json/json.php

Comment: It works now. But to enable some settings for this plugin I will include in my json.php wp-core files to get access to the options functions. Maybe there is any other way to insert all this functionality in the body of the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), then see if you can adapt this code to what Highcharts is wanting:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wpse_77392_get_json', 'wpse_77392_get_json');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse_77392_get_json', 'wpse_77392_get_json');

function wpse_77392_get_json() {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "
        SELECT `date`,`value`
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2011' AND '2012'
        ORDER BY `date` ASC;
    ";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $json = json_encode($results);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $json;
    exit;
}
```